# How to show loading spinner in on ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

Hello I have included given html code

```
#expressShippingCalculation    
  %li.list-group-item
    %label
      %input#shipping_method3{:name => "shipping_method", :type => "radio", :value => "1"}
        Shipping
        %small (Delivery within 4-5 days)
  %li.list-group-item#method4
    %label
      = form_for @order, :url => update_express_shipping_path,:method => 'patch', :html => { :id => "shippingDetails" }, :remote => true do |form|
        = form.radio_button :express_shipping, true, :value => true, :id => 'shipping_method4', :name => 'shipping_method'
        Express Shipping
        %small.maroonColorText (Additional Charge of USD 10 applicable.)
  #spinner.spinner{:style => "display:none;"}
    %img#img-spinner{:alt => "Loading", :src => "spinner.gif"}/
```

and js code is

```
$('#expressShippingCalculation input').change ->
    if $('#shipping_method4').is(':checked')
      additionalAmountExpress()
      data = $('#shippingDetails').serialize()
      expressValue = true
    else 
      $('#additional-charge').hide()
      expressValue = false
    $.ajax
      url: '/update_express_shipping?expressShipping=' +expressValue
      type: 'PATCH'
    return
```

Now I need to show loading spinner on my ajax request. lease guide me how I will include given code in my ajax request

```
$('#spinner').bind('ajaxSend', ->
  $(this).show()
  return
).bind('ajaxStop', ->
  $(this).hide()
  return
).bind 'ajaxError', ->
  $(this).hide()
  return
```

Please guide me how to include this code.

Comment: there are couple of things missing in code js code, 1. There is flower braces to mention define the block structure. 2. `$.ajax` contains callback for `success:` & `error:`, so you can place your show/hide spinner code in respective callbacks. **http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ref:**

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $('#spinner').show();
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $('#spinner').hide();
});
$(document).ajaxError(function(){
    $('#spinner').hide();
});
```

► [ajaxStart](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajaxstart.asp)

► [ajaxError](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajaxerror.asp)

► [ajaxComplete](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajaxcomplete.asp)